# Calculating average from a percent

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using DW to create record set that calculates the percentage from a table grouped by hospital name. I need to get the average of the percentage (by summation of the percentage divided by the number of hospital). I have only one table.

```
mysql_select_db($database_localapconnect, $localapconnect);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT    COUNT(IF(ap_intervalname = 'Less than or equal to 12 hours', ap_intervalname, NULL))/ COUNT(ap_intervalname) *100 AS 'percent' FROM maintble  GROUP BY `hospitalname`";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $localapconnect) or die(mysql_error());

$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset1)) {
print_r( $row_Recordset1['percent'].'<br>');    
}

print_r ($totalRows_Recordset1).'<br>' ;


echo  sum($row_Recordset1['percent'])/$totalRows_Recordset1;
```

result:

```
83.0189
98.0000
86.2745
68.0365
94.9686
78.4314

6
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sum() in C:\wamp\www\ap_database\Untitled-1.php on line 49

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: I think you are using SQL and PHP as if they were interchangeable. They aren't, they are different languages.

Comment: You might take a look at PHP's array_sum() function

Comment: [***sum** doesn't exist. Closest matches:*](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sum&scope=quickref)

Answer (score 1):

The function *sum* doesn't exist in PHP. If you want the sum of the elements of an array, you should use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

But, in this specific case, I think it's better sum inside the loop, because you are already accessing all the elements anyway...

For example, like this:

```
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
$sum = 0.0;
while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset1)) {
    print_r( $row_Recordset1['percent'].'<br>');    
    $sum += $row_Recordset1['percent'];
}


print_r ($totalRows_Recordset1).'<br>' ;

echo  $sum/$totalRows_Recordset1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT avg(percent)
FROM (SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN ap_intervalname = 'Less than or equal to 12 hours' THEN 100.0
                      ELSE 0 END) AS percent
      FROM maintble
      GROUP BY `hospitalname`
     ) m;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `sum()` in this line of php code.

```
 sum($row_Recordset1['percent'])/$totalRows_Recordset1; /* mistake */
```

But that doesn't make sense.  For one thing, `$row_Recordset1['percent']` is just a plain old number. For another thing, php doesn't have a built in `sum()` function.

If you don't want to use SQL to do that computation, you need to add up the values in your recordset processing loop.

```
$sum = 0.0;
$count = 0;
while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_array($Recordset1)) {
    $count ++;
    $sum += $row_Recordset1['percent'];
    print_r( $row_Recordset1['percent'].'<br>');    
}
echo  $sum / $count;
```

Notice I counted the rows explicitly rather than relying on `num_rows()`. That's for a good reason; under some circumstances `num_rows()` is not reliable before you read the recordset.

Comment: Thanks for you expert reply, still it doesn't result the average percent. I resorted to hard coding the sum of the denominator since it is more or less a fixed number..SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT(sum(vt)/6,1),'%') AS 'National Average' FROM (select count(`hospitalname`) as cnt, COUNT(IF(ap_intervalname = 'Less than or equal to 12 hours', ap_intervalname, NULL))/ COUNT(ap_intervalname) *100 as vt from maintble 
WHERE `dischargedt` BETWEEN coldatefrom AND coldateto
GROUP by `hospitalname`) a;